# Phoenix Elixir Association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a question about association in Phoenix Elixir, it happens When inserting a new customer, multiple associations occur between them, the Doc Schema receives the "customer_id" as well as the Contact and Debt Schema, all this works. But also in this transaction I want to associate the "doc_id" of the Doc schema created to the Debt schema, this does not work for me.

**Customer Schema**

```
 defmodule App.Customers.Customer do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias App.Customers.{ Contact, Doc, Debt }
  alias App.Collections.Collection

  schema "customers" do
    field :codLegal, :string
    field :businessName, :string
    field :fantasyName, :string
    has_many :contacts, Contact
    has_many :docs, Doc
    has_one :collection, Collection 
    has_many :debts, Debt

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(customer, attrs \\ %{}) do
    customer
    |> cast(attrs, [:codLegal, :businessName, :fantasyName])
    |> validate_required([:codLegal, :businessName, :fantasyName])
    |> unique_constraint(:codLegal)
    |> cast_assoc(:docs, with: &App.Customers.Doc.changeset/2)
    |> cast_assoc(:contacts, with: &App.Customers.Contact.changeset/2)
    |> cast_assoc(:debts, with: &App.Customers.Debt.changeset/2)
  end
end
```

**Doc Schema**

```
defmodule App.Customers.Doc do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias App.Customers.{ Doc, Customer, Debt }
  alias App.Collections.Collection

  schema "docs" do
    field :number, :string
    field :startdate, :date
    field :endate, :date
    field :type, :string
    belongs_to :customer, Customer
    many_to_many :collections, Collection, join_through: "collections_docs"
    has_one :debt, Debt

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(doc, attrs) do
    doc
    |> cast(attrs, [:type, :number, :startdate, :endate])
    |> validate_required([:type, :number, :startdate, :endate])
    |> unique_constraint(:number)
    |> cast_assoc(:debt, with: &App.Customers.Debt.changeset/2)
  end
end
```

**Debt Schema**

```
defmodule App.Customers.Debt do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias App.Customers.{ Customer, Doc }


  schema "debts" do
    field :credit, :integer
    field :debit, :integer
    belongs_to :doc, Doc
    belongs_to :customer, Customer

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(debt, attrs) do
    debt
    |> cast(attrs, [:debit, :credit])
    |> validate_required([:debit])
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? What error message do you get, if any? What code do you use that fails?

Comment: The doc_id of the transaction is not inserted in the debt schema.

Comment: Can you share the map that you are passing while inserting a new customer? If you want the `debt` to have `doc_id` then as per the relationship you have shared above the nesting has to be something like %{`docs`:  [%{debt: %{ }} ] }. So inside the key for `docs` which is a list each individual map will have a `debt` key and data related to that.